# What is the grammatical breakdown of phrases such as "fair of face", "strong of mind"?

Tags: nouns, prepositions, adjectives

The components of such phrases are: adjective + "of" + noun. Could you refer to the adjective as the qualifier of the noun? Or the noun as the object of the adjective? Is there one grammatical term that refers to these types of phrases?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  Can you offer any research on what you've tried to find out?

Comment: If anything, the prepositional phrase modifies the adjective, but this is an old, formal phrasing.